# Select list to associated array

Tags: javascript, html, json, select

I have a select with options and values:

```
<select id="sid">
<option value="sValue1">sText1</option>
...
</select>
```

I need to create an associated array for all pairs:

```
var data = {"sText1":"sValue1",...};
```

Is there ready/simplifies tools to do that?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a basic `for ... on ...` iteration.
Take note that if there are multiple `<option>` with the same label, the last one will take place in the result object.

```js
const select = document.getElementById('sid');
const objContainer = document.getElementById('sid-obj');
const options = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
const selectObj = {};
for (const opt of options) {
    let optObj = {};
    optObj[opt.textContent] = opt.value;
    Object.assign(selectObj, optObj);
}
// print result in code
objContainer.textContent = JSON.stringify(selectObj);
```

```html
<select id="sid">
  <option value="">Default</option>
  <option value="sValue1">sText1</option>
  <option value="sValue2">sText2</option>
  <option value="sValue3">sText3</option>
  <option value="sValue4">sText4</option>
  <option value="sValue5">sText4</option>
</select>

<h2>Result:</h2>
<code id="sid-obj" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to the `select` which will be called on change and on change get the value and the text from the selected option

```js
function getValue(elem) {
  let obj = {};
  obj[elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text] = elem.value
  console.log(obj)
}
```

```html
<select id="sid" onchange='getValue(this)'>
  <option value="sValue1">sText1</option>
  <option value="sValue2">sText2</option>
  <option value="sValue3">sText3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thought, it is clear that I need all text and values from select to be converted to an array. As for Your answer, the only edit I need is to know how many options are there

Comment: on what event ? is it multiselect?

Comment: Sorry, probably I should point more details: I am getting html page from Ajax response. It contains select (not multiselect). I need to grab out from that select all pairs `{"text1":"value1", "text2":"value2", ...}`. So in Your code there only should be added a loop for each `option`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late to the party but here is a `jQuery` solution for the same.

```js
var arr = {};
$("#sid option").each(function() {
  let text = $(this).text();
  arr[text] = $(this).val();
});
// print result
$('#sid-obj').append(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sid">
  <option value="">Default</option>
  <option value="sValue1">sText1</option>
  <option value="sValue2">sText2</option>
  <option value="sValue3">sText3</option>
  <option value="sValue4">sText4</option>
  <option value="sValue5">sText4</option>
</select>

<h2>Result:</h2>
<code id="sid-obj" />
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback, but I do not like jQuery, never use it.